# preg_match url current with function designed (condition), or better ideas

Tags: php, url, menu, preg-match

First of all, I dont know too much of this code, and I know it is very poor, forgive me.

In my website I had a deprecated code "ereg" that now I am trying to resolve with preg_match but I have no idea of this new PHP code.

```
function Menu($sitio) {
    $url = 'http://www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if(ereg($sitio, $url)) {echo 'class="totalactive"';}
}
```

As you can see, if I have a list with for example:

```
<li <?php Menu (/contact) ?>>
```

if you are in www.yourwebsite.com/contact the code works. (but i think there are better ways to do this, because i have problems with the principal page, and any other website that is not on this list.)

I think this code is too bad, and know with php5.3 or more is even more useless.

Is there a new way to do this with Preg_match detecting the site and setting by default one of them?. Or a totally new and better way to fix this with php5.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your `ereg` call by this.

```
preg_match("|" . preg_quote($sitio, "|") . "|", $url)
```

To only match the specified url you have to add a start and end sign to that regular expression like this:

```
preg_match("|^" . preg_quote($sitio, "|") . "$|", $url)
```

Comment: and if I have directly a comparaison instead of $sitio? Example: ereg('/contact',$url)

Comment: With `preg_replace` you always have to use delimiters in your regular expression. That example would be `preg_match('|/contact|', $url)`. Note that `|` is the delimiter.

Comment: It works perfectly thank you. But one more question, how can i put a default to one of this if anyone is TRUE? For example: url.com/faq.php (or any other thing outside your menu)

Comment: You should open another question for that.